# Authentication Form : Multi-users access

Tags: javascript, authentication

My web app is made using Html and Javascript, and runs under Apache tomcat. I made an authentication form , but I'm struggling in managing multi-users acess.

I'd like to grant each user the right to acess certain web pages.

It seems that plenty of the scripts that are online are made using PHP.

How should I write a simple javascript function, that controls the password authentication and grant each user access to the pages I define for him?

Any hint or help would be highly apreciated.

Comment: To do what you want you need a server side programming language, you can use Javascript via node.js for this.

Comment: You can't; JavaScript runs in the browser, so you can't directly control anything on the server (such as access control) from the JavaScript code itself. PHP, however, runs on the server side, which is why it *can* do this (and why you'll find so many scripts online that does this.)

Comment: @b2238488 ,@Frxstrem thanks for replying. In my case, there are only 3 users with predefined password and login. My idea is to control that in the javascript  function  inside the code. I don't know If there's a specific function in  javascript that I can use to allow each user to have acess to certain web pages.

Comment: You can ask the user for login credentials and store their account information in a cookie in the browser. Then you can load pages for the user using javascript, apart from the traditional method, and load just the pages that each user has access too. However, this method is extremely easy to break since any user can just change the JS and access whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is just html and javascript you might be better using Apache httpd instead of Apache tomcat. Authentication can be backed by files or directories (like LDAP), and authorization can be configured per Location/directory. You can also get the logged user from apache httpd and use it in your javascript.